# Python ThreadPool process hang

Tags: python, threadpool, freeze

```
import sys
import os
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import importlib
from time import gmtime, strftime
import shutil



def check(USERINFO):
    try:
        DO SOMETHING
    except:
        pass
    else:
        try:
            DO SOMETHING
        except:
            pass
        else:
            DO SOMETHING

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file = sys.argv[1]
    p = ThreadPool(processes=int(sys.argv[2]),)
    combos = []
    for x in list(set(open(file, 'r').readlines())):
        combos.append(x)
    p.map(check, combos)
    p.close() 
    p.join()
```

I have application just like that, simple but somehow sometimes process stuck because of "hang" processes.This is too simple script there is no way to getting any error im using error handle on everywhere, idk what problem is but tried almost everything.

edit : python version 2.7.14

Comment: Not related at all, but just so you know, `open(file, 'r').readlines()` can cause a potential memory leak (in this specific case, there's no harm), as you lose your only reference to the file handle.

Comment: this script just for personal usage, really only problem that "hanging" thing at this moment.

Comment: well after few days i solved my problem with pebble library and timeouts.